# Php extensions on centos7 php7.x

Tags: centos, php

I am trying to test phpmyfaq on local development and I met with this error :

```
The following extensions are missing! Please enable the PHP extensions(s) in php.ini : ext/zip
```

I run php -m on command line and i don't see any zip .
   I tried : `yum install php70-php-pcel-zip.x86_64`

But it still doesn't appear on `php -m`. 
I am running Centos7 on VMware player, php version 7.0.26

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention , i did :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved by doing

```
yum --enablerepo=epel install php-pecl-zip
```

Comment: It's *so* counter-intuitive!! `php-zip` should do this, but the `zip.so` is absolutely missing!!